# How to override program.cs to disable authentication and authorization for ASP.NET Core Razor Pages web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this test class that fails with an error.

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Response status code does not
> indicate success: 302 (Found).

If I manually commented out the code for authentication and authorization in `program.cs`, the test class works as expected.

In program.cs (I am using .NET 6):

```
//builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
//        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
//            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/"); // apply the [Authorize] attribute to all pages for all folders
//        })
//        .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
```

How to override `program.cs` in my test class to disable authentication and authorization for ASP.NET Core Razor Pages web app?

This is my test class:

```
public class IntegrationTests : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Program>> {
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory;

    public IntegrationTests(WebApplicationFactory<Program> factory) {
        _factory = factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
        {
            // Override the services configuration for testing
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                // Remove the authorization policy for Razor Pages                    
                services.AddRazorPages();

            });
        });
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("/")]
    public async Task Get_EndpointsReturnSecurePageAsync(string url) {
        // Arrange
        var client = _factory.CreateClient();

        // Act
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

        // Assert
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Status Code 200-299
        Assert.Equal("text/html; charset=utf-8",
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question. Why do you want to disable auth?

Comment: The test is to test the page performance. Just temporary.

Comment: how 302 (Found) is related to auth?

Comment: @YehorAndrosov, i think so. After I commented out the code related to authentication and authorization, the test passed.

Comment: ah, I forgot that 302 is a redirect. Probably it redirects to login page. I guess, the only  option is to have a credentials defined in the test code.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I want to disable auth as I don't want to test auth in my test class. I want to focus on testing the page performance first.

Comment: So you want to use your normal `ConfigureServices` method... `.AddRazorPagesOptions()` will define an `IConfigureOptions<RazorPagesOptions>` service that you could remove from the service collection...? (or add another implementation to remove the conventions...?)

Comment: Otherwise, I suppose you could instead redefine the default / fallback auth policies to allow anonymous access.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, how it can be done? Can post as answer with code?

Comment: Create a Program.cs just for your test, put there only the thing you need to complete that test, in that new class don't add `` options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/")```

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation at [Integration tests in ASP.NET Core - Mock authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#mock-authentication)

> The test app can mock an AuthenticationHandler in ConfigureTestServices in order to test aspects of authentication and authorization.

Code examples given in the above link:

```cs
public class TestAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    public TestAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Test user") };
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Test");
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, "TestScheme");

        var result = AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

Add the authentication handler to the services collection used in the test:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task Get_SecurePageIsReturnedForAnAuthenticatedUser()
{
    // Arrange
    var client = _factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
        {
            builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddAuthentication(defaultScheme: "TestScheme")
                    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, TestAuthHandler>(
                        "TestScheme", options => { });
            });
        })
        .CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
        {
            AllowAutoRedirect = false,
        });

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue(scheme: "TestScheme");

    //Act
    var response = await client.GetAsync("/SecurePage");

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
}
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: It would be helpful with a better description than "it doesn't work". I have created a .NET 6 project and applied your configuration so that it always redirects to the login page when run. Then I added a xUnit test project and basically copied the code from my answer above (I changed the requestUri to "/" in the client.GetAsync() call) and it works on my computer™ (the test is passing).

Comment: Actually which part of your code disables the authentication? @nikstra

Comment: @Steve It doesn't disable authentication but adds the TestAuthHandler which basically returns AuthenticateResult.Success(). It also uses AllowAutoRedirect = false option when creating the client so that the 302 redirect is ignored and the controller action is called. If you really want to disable auth, I think that you can use a preprocessor directive like #if NOAUTH to wrap the AddRazorPages() call but I don't know how to tell the test runner to set NOAUTH.

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing the configured `RazorPagesOptions` options before calling the `AddRazorPages`:

```cs
public IntegrationTests(WebApplicationFactory<Program> factory) {
    _factory = factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
    {
        // Override the services configuration for testing
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            // Remove the authorization policy for Razor Pages  
            services.RemoveAll<IConfigureOptions<RazorPagesOptions>>();     
            services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(_ => {});
        });
    });
}
```

Or just:

```cs
public IntegrationTests(WebApplicationFactory<Program> factory) {
    _factory = factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
    {
        // Override the services configuration for testing
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            // Remove the authorization policy for Razor Pages  
            services.RemoveAll<IConfigureOptions<RazorPagesOptions>>();     
            services.AddRazorPages();
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an environment variable will do it. How safe this is from a security perspective is another question.

Check if the variable is set in program.cs:

```cs
if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEST_NO_AUTH") == "enabled")
{
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
}
else
{
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/"); // apply the [Authorize] attribute to all pages for all folders
        })
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
}
```

Then set the variable in the tests constructor.

```cs
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TEST_NO_AUTH", "enabled");
```